# Ersatzinfinitiv

Tags: sentence-structure, german-to-english, word-order, verb-usage

1.In some verbs, the past participle in the compound tenses is replaced by the present infinitive when it comes immediately after an infinitive,examples below:

ex) Er hilft ihm den Wagen waschen --> Er hat ihm den Wagen waschen helfen

ex) Weil er ihm den Wagen hat waschen helfen

Then my question is like this : This From can also be used as a 'passive form' ? If it is possible, how can it be formed ?

A -> Ihm wurde den Wagen waschen helfen.

B -> Ihm wurde den Wagen waschen geholfen.

Is it also possible ?

C -> Ihm ist den wagen worden waschen helfen.

D -> Ihm ist den wagen worden waschen geholfen.

I would appreciate it if someone could give the English equivalents of these structures.

Comment: These all sound kinda weird and Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv) mentions that (hören, fühlen, helfen) as sometwhat unregular in that regard. So maybe try it with different verb.

Comment: You just asked that on Reddit, but from a different angle.  ex 1 the version after the arrow is wrong as is ex2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to dump a bunch of iterations here:

With "zu"

- Er hilft ihm, den Wagen zu waschen.
- Er hat ihm geholfen, den Wagen zu waschen.
- Er hat ihm den Wagen zu waschen geholfen. (sounds awful)
- Ihm wurde geholfen, den Wagen zu waschen.
- Ihm ist geholfen worden, den Wagen zu waschen.
- Ihm ist den Wagen zu waschen geholfen worden.

Without zu:

- Er hilft ihm den Wagen waschen.
- Er hat ihm den Wagen waschen geholfen.
- Er hat ihm geholfen, den Wagen waschen. WRONG!!!
- Ihm wurde den Wagen waschen geholfen. ("correct" but sounds awful)
- Ihm ist den Wagen waschen geholfen worden. (again, correct but bad)

There isn't the one equivalent phrasing in English for most of them. They convey a certain concept which you have multiple options to express in English.

Comment: Thank you.How about: Ihm wurde geholfen/ist geholfen worden, den Wagen zu waschen.

Ihm wurde den Wagen zu waschen geholfen./Ihm ist den Wagen zu waschen geholfen worden.

Comment: @Emanuel The problem is that he/she is explicitly asking for the Ersatzinfinitiv so when you use the infinitive instead of the past participate. Like helfen instead of geholfen. So while your sentences sound objectively better, you've kinda missed the point with that answer.

Comment: @iamshimye, yes, those work as well.

Comment: @haxor789 the title is "Ersatzinfinitiv", yes, but I do not see how the question is about that. I don't understand what the question is trying to solve overall, except the person just wants to play around and see what's possible with passive tense and word order. There's nothing asked specifically about Ersatzinfinitiv.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both sentences marked with "ex" are wrong, because they lack a "zu":

> Er hilft ihm, den Wagen **zu** waschen.

The version after the arrow is also wrong, it needs a PPP (Partizip Perfekt Passiv) instead of an infinitive:

> Er hat ihm den Wagen (zu) waschen **geholfen**.

The past tense is "hat geholfen", not "hat helfen". The main sentence parses out like this:

> Er [Subjekt/Nomen] hat geholfen [Prädikat/Verb].
> Er hat ihm [Dativ-Objekt/Personalpronomen] geholfen.

For the last addition there are two different possibilities which mean the same:

> Er hat ihm geholfen den Wagen zu waschen.
> Er hat ihm den Wagen zu waschen geholfen.

The second sentence marked "ex" is not a main sentence and shouldn't stand on its own. Relative sentences have a different word order than main sentences and this may have caused to confusion. Even then, "helfen" needs to be replaced with "geholfen" for reasons stated above. A possible sentence would be:

> Weil er ihm den Wagen hat waschen **geholfen**, *lud er ihn anschließend auf ein Eis ein*.

Here, the part about the treating to an ice is the main sentence, the part before is only the justification of what the main sentence is about.

The *Ersatzinfinitiv* has no place in either of these sentences because they all need the normal perfect form "haben + PPP". You need the Ersatzinfinitiv when you have one verb depending on another AND the verb the other is depending on is a modal verb ("wollen", "sollen", "können", "mögen", "müssen", "dürfen" and "lassen"), i.e.:

> Er hat ihm den Wagen zu waschen helfen *wollen*.

In some cases (not in all, mind you, and not in your examples) the same is true for: "brauchen", "heißen", "hören", "fühlen", "sehen" and "helfen".

> Er hat ihn den Wagen waschen *sehen*.

> Er hätte den Wagen nicht zu waschen *brauchen*.